# Cannot sort integer field index correctly in RavenDB

Tags: .net, ravendb

I can't seem to get an integer field to sort correctly.

I have the field defined with a Sort of int:

[image]

When I query it in the management studio by this field descending, the results sort correctly:

[image]

However, my understanding is when using `OrderByDescending` using LINQ in .NET, it will use the `MaximumReach_Range` field, which I've confirmed in Fiddler:

[image]

But when I sort by that in the Management Studio or call `OrderByDescending` using LINQ in .NET, the order is wrong:

[image]

I'm fairly sure that it's an issue with how the field is set up in the index, but I'm not sure which aspect outside of the `Sort` value needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key was in the `Indexing` value for the field, it must be set to `Default` in order for the range field to be set up correctly for integer sorting.

[image]

Comment: It did not work for me :\ I still have a bad range sort.